# XPST0017: The function call 'math:random' does not match the name of a function in the static context

Tags: xslt-2.0, xmlspy

I've a xml and xsl and I am trying to do the transformation using XMLSPY 2023 professional edition. The xsl has

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
xmlns:math="java.lang.Math
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

and some where inside a template refers to math.random() as shown below:

```
<xsl:variable name="randonId" select="math:random()"/>
```

Now I do XSL/XQUERY --> XSL Transformation from the menu item in XML SPY editor, it throws this error below. Any idea what setting I should to fix this error?

XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: An Error occurred while trying to start the debugger! (Error: file:///C:/myxsl.xsl:648: Unknown function 'math:random'  Details:    XPST0017: The function call 'math:random' does not match the name of a function in the static context)

Comment: I don't know whether XMLSpy supports calling into Java, as you seem to want to do. However, it supports XSLT 3.0 with XPath 3.1 which has its function `fn:random-number-generator` without needing Java. So you might want to try e.g. `version="3.0"` and then e.g. `random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?number`.

Comment: I changed the namespace as <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:fn="https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/xpath-functions"  and used the below code <xsl:variable name="myRandom" select="fn:random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?number"/> . But I still get error as Unknown function 'fn:random-number-generator' What should I do? What should be my import should be?

Comment: Well, my suggestion was to try `version="3.0"` and then just the unprefixed call `random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?number`. If you want to use the `fn` prefix, make sure you use the right function namespace which I think is `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`. So try without a prefix and `version="3.0"`, if you think you want a prefix like `fn` (do you do that for other XPath functions like `replace` or `substring`?) then make sure you use the right one (my recollection is the one I have shown but I haven't checked against the spec).

Comment: I have checked with https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#namespace-prefixes and the right namespace URI for the prefix `fn` is indeed `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions`

Comment: Thanks. I still get errors with both the approach. May be I am doing some other mistake. I tried by without the prefix fn name space in the header it still throw error. Also, I tried with xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" . It still throws the error. The error is: XSL transformation failed due to following error:

'current-dateTime' is not a valid XSLT or XPath function. 

random-number-generator(-->current-dateTime()<--)?number

Comment: Works fine for me at https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj3-saxonhe12-fiddle/?code=random-number-generator%28current-dateTime%28%29%29%3Fnumber&input=&code-type=XPath&input-type=None with Saxon. No idea why XMLSpy 2023 wouldn't support or rather what could have gone wrong. Perhaps better ask Altova support, if nobody here shows up with XMLSpy/Altova experience.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It works when run from command prompt using saxon. I am using xmlspy only to debug and see where my transformation is failing for my other issues.